# Java Heap Size Error

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt, heap-memory, mahout-recommender

i am basically building a movie reccomendation system with apache mahout, but i am using a 540MB dataset which occurs this problem in execution

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
.
.etc..
.
  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
```

So that i searched on web and learned that this is problem is coming from the heap size which you can see from the exception  "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m" part , and i tried to change it in eclipse from -> run configurations ->Vm parameters but its not working so that i opened a command prompt in my class file path(File , Shift+Ctrl , Open Command Window Here)  and i wrote these to change the limits minimum to 512 maximum to 1024

```
>java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m SuggestionMain
```

But this time , another exception occured which is below

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/cf/
taste/model/DataModel
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.Da
taModel
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I couldn't understand and solve the problem here so can anyone help me to solve the memory problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What kind of application is this (e.g. Stand alone application (public static void main(String[] args), a web application (if yes what are you using for a server), etc.).

Comment: Are you sure those two errors are related? Maybe you have a bug in your code separate from the heap size problem that causes the class definition error.

Comment: Those errors are unrelated. ClassNotFoundException is pretty much self explanatory, you're missing a dependency somewhere.

Comment: I am just trying the recomender so that i am using standart java apllication  (public static void main(String[] args) and there is no bug in the code cause i am  taking codes from mahout 's offical site :D and there is only 6 lines of code :D the only thing that i change is the dataset

Comment: @Durandal i just explained everyting to people so that maybe i missed something and maybe you are true :D i am checking every dependency but even if there is then isnt the program crashes when i am running in eclipse ? In mahout's site they also suggest progrrammers to increase the heap size